# Table.FillDown with continuous numbers in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset in Power BI, where I want to fill down values with continuous numbers in M-Language in some sort of `Table.FillDown` function.

I have an ID column and can identify the first of each ID. I value 1 in column R_ID, and I want to fill down numbers in Datatable A.

My expected output table is Datatable B where the numbers increment by 1 in null-rows and restart at 1 when the value 1 occurs.

I hope somebody has a viable solution to this problem.

Datatable A:

```
ID      R_ID
4545    1
4545    null
3973    1
3973    null
3973    null
3973    null
3973    null
5492    1
5492    null
5492    null
3244    1
3244    null
3244    null
3244    null
```

Datatable B:

```
ID      R_ID
4545    1
4545    2
3973    1
3973    2
3973    3
3973    4
3973    5
5492    1
5492    2
5492    3
3244    1
3244    2
3244    3
3244    4
```